# Choosing combination based on constraints

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on making my first program and I am not quite sure how to move forward. Basically the program is meant to make balanced teams based on player ranks. I've managed to iterate through all the combinations of possible teams and display the total rank (sum of players ranks on the team) of each team.

(I wont include all the code just because it's a bit lengthy)

Current code:

```
players = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4}

compPoss = list(it.combinations(players.items(), int(numPlayers/numTeams))) #Creating possible combinations of teams

for row in compPoss:

    # initialize variables:
    row_sum = 0

    # iterate over each point (tuple):
    for point in row:

        # convert number to int:
        number = int(point[1])

        # add to sum:
        row_sum += number

    #to add sum of rows to end of row
    new_compPoss = row + (row_sum,)

    # print row and sum:
    print(new_compPoss)
```

Output

```
(('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), 3)
(('A', '1'), ('C', '3'), 4)
(('A', '1'), ('D', '4'), 5)
(('B', '2'), ('C', '3'), 5)
(('B', '2'), ('D', '4'), 6)
(('C', '3'), ('D', '4'), 7)
```

I now want to print the teams that have the smallest difference in rank while also having unique players. In this example it would be :

```
Team 1 ('A','D') Rank 5

Team 2 ('B','C') Rank 5
```

How could I achieve this? Do I need to import a specific library? If so which one?

Comment: You don't need to convert number to `int` because it's `int` already.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` you use is OK here.

Python has built-in [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [list comprehensions](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) so you don't need to write that much of code. This is what you've got as an output:

```
ranks = []
for row in compPoss:
    row_sum = sum(point[1] for point in row)
    new_compPoss = row + (row_sum,)
    ranks.append(new_compPoss)
```

So list of ranks consists of items that you are printing. You can use this output to iterate through pairs that have smallest differences in rank, check if it forms unique players and return first such pair. But I think a work it's quite hard here.

I prefer to find all the pairs that have unique players already formed and then return one that has smallest difference in rank. If you have some `team1`, you can find what are remaining members of `team2` and find rank differences of these two teams:

```
import itertools as it
players = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4}
compPoss = list(it.combinations(players, 2)) #Creating possible combinations of teams, like ('A', 'C')

set_of_players = set(players)
rank_differences = []
for row in compPoss:
    team1 = row
    team2 = set_of_players - set(row) #finding remaining members
    team1_rank = sum(players[n] for n in team1)
    team2_rank = sum(players[n] for n in team2)
    rank_differences.append((team1, tuple(team2), abs(team2_rank - team1_rank)))

for n in rank_differences:
    print(n)
```

It gives result:

```
(('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), 4)
(('A', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), 2)
(('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), 0)
(('B', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), 0)
(('B', 'D'), ('C', 'A'), 2)
(('C', 'D'), ('B', 'A'), 4)
```

All the items are duplicated but you can ignore it and print the one that has smallest rank difference like so:

```
>>> result = min(rank_differences, key = lambda x: x[2])
>>> print(result)
(('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), 0)
```

#### Extra hack

You can use property that combinations are sorted in lexicographic order, it means remaining teams can be accessed in reversed list of combinations:

```
>>> compPoss
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
# first half of combinations: [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D')]
team1_groups = compPoss[:len(compPoss)//2]
# another half of combinations: [('C', 'D'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'C')]
team2_groups = compPoss[:len(compPoss)//2-1:-1] 

pairs = zip(team1_groups, team2_groups)

rank_differences = []
for team1, team2 in pairs:
    team1_rank = sum(players[n] for n in team1)
    team2_rank = sum(players[n] for n in team2)
    rank_differences.append((team1, team2, abs(team2_rank - team1_rank)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That solution is great for the example I provided, however number of players as well as number of teams is based on user input. So there could be 3 teams of 5 players each. Sorry about that I should have been more clear, although I will use the advice you gave to clean up my code.